# How do I join tables while preserving the exact information on one table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to join two tables by matching a time in one table with a period (a start and end time) on the second, and I need to do this so that the operation preserves the exact information on one table. More specifically, I have these tables.

Table t1:

```
cid   time1
A     2016-01-05 11:00:00
A     2016-01-15 11:00:00
A     2016-01-25 11:00:00
B     2016-01-09 11:00:00
```

Table t2:

```
cid   period_start          period_end
A     2016-01-01 00:00:00   2016-01-10 00:00:00
A     2016-01-10 00:00:00   2016-01-16 00:00:00
A     2016-01-12 00:00:00   2016-01-20 00:00:00
```

And I want the output as:

```
cid   time1                 period_start          period_end
A     2016-01-05 11:00:00   2016-01-01 00:00:00   2016-01-10 00:00:00
A     2016-01-15 11:00:00   2016-01-10 00:00:00   2016-01-16 00:00:00
A     2016-01-25 11:00:00   NULL                  NULL
B     2016-01-09 11:00:00   NULL                  NULL
```

A few additional information/conditions:

- I want the information on t1 preserved exactly in the output (e.g., no rows on t1 joined to multiple rows on t2, no rows from t1 missing in the output). In other words, I just want information from t2 added to t1 as columns.
- If there is no period in t2 that includes time1 on t1, I want period_start and period_end to be NULL.
- There might also be no matching cid on t2 at all.
- If there are multiple matches on t2, I want only the first one.

Right now I have:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.period_start, t2.period_end
FROM t1
  LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.cid = t2.cid
WHERE t2.period_start >= t1.time1
AND t2.period_end <= t1.time1
```

but it doesn't properly handle the scenario where there is no match. How can I do this?

I a doing this on Redshift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want only the first matching row from `t2`, you could use a `LATERAL` subquery with a `LIMIT` clause:

```
SELECT t1.cid, t1.time1, t2.period_start, t2.period_end
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN LATERAL
     (SELECT *
      FROM t2
      WHERE cid=t1.cid AND t1.time1 BETWEEN period_start AND period_end
      ORDER BY t2.period_start
      LIMIT 1
     ) t2 ON true
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the filters on t2 from the where clause to the join

```
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ep ON t1.cid = t2.cid
and t2.period_start >= t1.time1
AND t2.period_end <= t1.time1
```

When you filter on the left joined table in the where clause, the type of join is changed to inner.

Comment: It doesn't work for me because Jan 15 in t1 gets joined to two rows in t2. I only want the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT cid, time1, period_start, period_end
FROM (
   SELECT t1.cid, t1.time1, t2.period_start, t2.period_end,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.cid, t1.time1
                             ORDER BY t2.period_start) AS rn
   FROM t1
   LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.cid = t2.cid AND 
                   t1.time1 BETWEEN t2.period_start AND t2.period_end) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

`ROW_NUMBER` is used in order to pick one record from `t1` table in case of multiple matches.